# Context > preview to display animation, of animated gifs?

Tags: windows, animated-gif, windows-photo-viewer

I'm using `preview` in my `context menu` which opens the default image viewer, `Windows Photo Viewer`.

### Actual behavior

When opened, an `animated gif` file is opened, but the animation is not played--it's like the image is paused.

### Desired behavior

I want `Windows Photo Viewer` to go through the animation.

### Questions

Is the desired behavior possible via `Windows Photo Viewer`?  If not, can I replace the `preview` action with another action--have `preview` open a different app?  If so, which softwares take `hotkeys`, like the `left-right d-pad arrow keys` to go to the `next/previous` image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue, and has a few solutions online. Here's one I like from github.

https://github.com/Corgano/Windows7GifViewer/blob/master/Windows7GifViewer.exe

Go there, click "View Raw" to download the EXE, and run it.

Comment: works better than anything at the dup.

Comment: Actually, 4th answer at the dupe has a link to this one. :)